# Show that the sequence $(x_n)=\left( \sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1 i\right)$ diverge by epsilon delta definition.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Show that the sequence $\displaystyle (x_n)=\left( \sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1 i\right)$ diverge by epsilon delta definition.

I'm not familiar with proving divergent sequence. Do anyone have any des? Thank you.

Comment: I just know epsilon delta definition, nothing else. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with the comparison test?

> Let $\sum x_n$ and $\sum y_n$ be series with $x_n\ge y_n\ge 0$ for sufficiently large $n$. Then if $\sum y_n$ diverges, $\sum x_n$ diverges.

So you just need to compare it with a divergent series from below.

Answer (score 1):

For $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\forall n ,  \displaystyle|x_{2n}-x_n|=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}\geq n\times\frac{1}{2n}=\epsilon$ hence the sequence $(x_n)$ is divergent since it's not a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Estimate from below the sums $A_n=\sum_{i=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1}\frac 1i$.